# unable to access image from request in django

Tags: reactjs, django, request, payload

I am trying to send images in FormData() from react to django. But not images is recieving in the django server. Other text fields are showing in QueryDict but images are not there.

react code -

```
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('title', ref_title.current.value);
formdata.append('price',ref_price.current.value);
formdata.append('description',ref_desc.current.value);
formdata.append('images',ref_image.current.files[0],ref_image.current.files[0].name);
console.log(formdata.get('images'));
axios.post(url, formdata).then(res => {
(res.status == 200)?alert('success'):alert('error');
})
```

django code -

```
print(request.POST.get('title'))
print(request.POST.get('price'))
print(request.POST.get('images'))   # it is returning None
print(request.POST)
```

I am getting the following output in django

> hello
>
> 41
>
> None
>
> <QueryDict: {'title': ['hello'], 'price': ['41'], 'description': ['hello world']}>

There is no images key in QueryDict. How can I access the image?

Comment: you can try `request.FILES` per the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads

Comment: @JimmyPells found image there. Thanks